# Give WPF application access to a shared drive but not the user

Tags: .net

I have a WPF application that will provide the users at our company a way to download and upload files to a directory that is on a windows server.  The application will be installed on each company members own machine.

We would like it so that the user cannot directly access the directory in a file browser, so they couldn't just go to: "\fileserver\files" and mess around.  They can only use the application to upload/download files.

What's the best way to set up permissions for this situation? Can we just create a user on the server and have the app hold the credentials for that user?

Comment: Sounds about right. have your app run under a service account and only give that account rights to the folder.

Comment: What method does this application use to access the files?

Comment: @DeanOC Just how do you have an app run under a service account?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of your app would be running under IIS, so you could create an app pool for that app and specify a domain account that the app pool runs under. That domain account could be given the access privileges to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to look into impersonation. You can have your application execute code under another user. Try setting up an account on the server that you want your application to execute code under.

Doing it this way means your code is only impersonating the user during the using statement, and not running as the other user for the applications entire lifespan.

This class supports cross domain impersonation as well as same domain.

```
C#    
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace Utils
{
    public class dvImpersonator : IDisposable
    {
        private WindowsImpersonationContext ImpersonationContext = null;
        enum LogonType
        {
            Interactive = 2,
            Network = 3,
            Batch = 4,
            Service = 5,
            Unlock = 7,
            NetworkClearText = 8,
            NewCredentials = 9
        }
        enum LogonProvider
        {
            Default = 0,
            WinNT35 = 1,
            WinNT40 = 2,
            WinNT50 = 3
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName"></param>
        /// <param name="domainName"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool LogOn(string _UserName, string _DomainName, string _Password)
        {
            return ImpersonateValidUser(_UserName, _DomainName, _Password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE);
        }

        public bool CrossDomainLogOn(string _UserName, string _DomainName, string _Password)
        {
            return ImpersonateValidUserCrossDomain(_UserName, _DomainName, _Password);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UndoImpersonation();
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int LogonUserA(
                      string lpszUserName,
                      string lpszDomain,
                      string lpszPassword,
                      int dwLogonType,
                      int dwLogonProvider,
                      ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int DuplicateToken(
               IntPtr hToken,
               int impersonationLevel,
               ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool RevertToSelf();


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(
                 IntPtr handle);


        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;


        /// <summary>
        /// Does the actual impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        private bool ImpersonateValidUser(string _UserName, string _Domain, string _Password, int provider)
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
            int iRet = 0;
            if (RevertToSelf())
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("here 1");
                if ((iRet = LogonUserA(_UserName, _Domain, _Password,
                    provider, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token)) != 0)
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        ImpersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        if (ImpersonationContext != null)
                        {
                            CloseHandle(token);
                            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }


                }
                //Console.WriteLine("iret " + iRet);
            }
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
            return false;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Does the actual impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        private bool ImpersonateValidUserCrossDomain(string _UserName, string _Domain, string _Password)
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
            int iRet = 0;
            if (RevertToSelf())
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("here 1");
                if ((iRet = LogonUserA(_UserName, _Domain, _Password,
                    (int)LogonType.NewCredentials, (int)LogonProvider.WinNT50, ref token)) != 0)
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        ImpersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        if (ImpersonationContext != null)
                        {
                            CloseHandle(token);
                            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }


                }
                //Console.WriteLine("iret " + iRet);
            }
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
            return false;

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Reverts the impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        private void UndoImpersonation()
        {
            if (ImpersonationContext != null)
            {
                ImpersonationContext.Undo();
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Sample Usage:

C#

```
using (var LogOn = new Utils.dvImpersonator())
{
    LogOn.CrossDomainLogOn(this.oConfig.User, this.oConfig.Domain, this.oConfig.Password);

       //Code to Execute as other users
}
```

You could also have a server side WCF service that has a method for upload, and a method for download. Then consume the WCF service in your WPF app, and have your WCF server side service running under an account with access to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. To follow up, this solution works very well for me. The impersonation seems to be lost right after the "//Code to Execute as other users" which is perfect.  I ended up calling LogOn.LogOn instead of LogOn.CrossDomainLogOn, other than that the code worked as is.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help, it was rather annoying figuring that out the first time on my own. I normally call the object in the using statement Auth, so it's Auth.LogOn or Auth.CrossDomainLogon, a bit wordy, I may change it to Auth.CrossDomain.